# How to change default permissions of files created by a process?

Tags: centos, permissions, games

I'm running a game server (unreal tournament 2004) on Centos 6 x86. I use a sh script to start it in a background process. This process (game server) creates different files (demos, logs) and they all come with 0600 permission by default. I have to process them with some applications so what I want is to change their default permission (to 0644 for example).

I'm root, I have umask 022 and files I create are 0644 by default. But it seems like this game server process don't inherit my umask. How can I change it? I'm pretty new to linux so a detailed answer would be appreciated.

Script used for running server:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Set the following to your UT2004 directory.
UT2004HOME=/home/ut2004

LOG=Server1.log

if [ ! -d "$UT2004HOME/Logs" ]; then
mkdir $UT2004HOME/Logs
fi

cd $UT2004HOME/System

while true; do

./ucc-bin server DM-Rankin-FE?game=XGame.xDeathMatch?Mutator=UTzoneTAv1.MutUTzoneTA,utcompv17a.MutUTComp,XWeapons.MutNoSuperWeapon,XGame.MutNoAdrenaline?MaxPlayers=2?DoubleDamage=False?TimedOverTimeLength=0?GameStats=True?AntiTCCSettings=NoMidGameChecks ini=server1.ini -nohomedir -lanplay &> $UT2004HOME/Logs/$LOG

DATE=20`date +%y%m%d`-`date +%H%M%S`
mv $UT2004HOME/Logs/$LOG $UT2004HOME/Logs/crash-$DATE.log

done;
```

I put it in an sh file and then start it in putty shell as root as a background process using & on the end of string.

#### UPDATE #1

Output from `ls -ld $UT2004HOME/Logs`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 1 10:22 /home/ut2004/Logs
```

files in this directory are `rw-r--r--`.

The output for 2 other directories that contain files I need to be `rwxr-xr-x` is the same:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 45056 Sep 26 14:16 /home/ut2004/Demos 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 28672 Sep 26 18:03 /home/ut2004/UserLogs
```

but files in them are `rw-------`

When I ran the command `file ./ucc-bin` it was reported to be a binary file.

Comment: Can you either post your script or provide a URL to where you got it?

Comment: Done. 1st post is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you also include the output of the directory too? `ls -ld $UT2004HOME/Logs`. also is the file `/ucc-bin` a script or a binary file? Run the command `file ./ucc-bin`.

Comment: The output for it is:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 10:22 /home/ut2004/Logs`
files in it are rw-r--r--
The output for 2 other directories that contain files I need to be rwxr-xr-x is the same:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 45056 Sep 26 14:16 /home/ut2004/Demos`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 28672 Sep 26 18:03 /home/ut2004/UserLogs`
but files in them are rw-------

ucc-bin is a binary file

Answer (score 4):

What user is the game server running as? Typically servers/services are run as users other than root so you'll need to figure out which user this is and change that user's `umask`.

You can set that user's `umask` in the user's `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`, though I would caution doing this without thinking about it first.

It might make more sense to set a ACL (Access Control List) on the directories in question so that other users can access them in addition to the user the game server is running as.

For this you'll use the tools `setfacl` and `getfacl`. For example:

```
# for a single user (userA)
$ setfacl -Rm d:u:userA:rwX,u:userA:rwX /var/www

# for a shared group (groupA) 
$ setfacl -Rm d:g:groupA:rwX,u:groupA:rwX /var/www
```

Or to make the directories read only:

```
$ setfacl -Rm d:u:www-data:rX,u:www-data:rX /var/www
```

#### UPDATE #1

OK so I downloaded what I think you're using. I downloaded the dedicated servers from here, on a page titled:  [Various useful downloads for Unreal, Unreal Tournament and Unreal Tournament 2004](http://www.margrave.myzen.co.uk/Downloads.html#UnrealTournamentDedicatedServers).

When I run a command, similar to yours I'm getting my log created with the permissions,

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1140 Sep 27 08:57 sams.log
```

This is the command I run:

```
$ ./ucc-bin masterserver -nohomedir -lanplay &> sams.log
```

And my umask is set to 002 as well. Can you please confirm what I've done here so that I know I'm copying your setup correctly?

#### References

- [setfacl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)
- [getfacl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl)
- [ACL tutorial](http://www.cs.unc.edu/cms/help/help-articles/posix-acls-in-linux)
- [Installing the UT dedicated server on Linux](http://www.margrave.myzen.co.uk/SettingupUTdedicatedserver.html)
- [Various useful downloads for Unreal, Unreal Tournament and Unreal Tournament 2004](http://www.margrave.myzen.co.uk/Downloads.html#UnrealTournamentDedicatedServers)

Comment: For a daemon started by a system user, files like `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are irrelevant. That user may not even have an existing home directory, and certainly won't be running shell initialization files.

Comment: @slm, currently I run it as root which has 0022 umask by default. I tried adding umask to .bashrc and .bash_profile, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Dragonheart - see updates. FYI when I run `./ucc-bin server ...` I get an error message: `Failed to load 'CityIntro.unr': Can't find file 'CityIntro.unr'`

Comment: @slm, well, I took a dedicated server package of 3339 ver.: [link](http://downloads.unrealadmin.org/UT2004/Server/), then updated it with 3369-2 linux patch: [link](http://downloads.unrealadmin.org/UT2004/Patches/Linux/). Info on setting up the server is here:[link](http://wiki.unrealadmin.org/Server_Setup_(UT2004)) - you have to use `./ucc-bin server` command, not the `masterserver`, just like in my script, which i've got at: [link](http://forums.epicgames.com/archive/index.php/t-359541.html).

Comment: @slm, Log files are created with the same permissions as in your case for me, but UserLogs and Demos are `rw-------`

Answer (score 0):

If that application don't have home directory , then you can define `umask` in  /etc/init.d script, where it from start.

You just need to add at top after shebang, `umask 0022` then files will be create with `644` permission.